# HTTPS Elastic load balancing with Amazon certificate manager is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

What I'm trying to do is making successful access to

https://example.com

http://example.com works well, but https:// does not.

I'm using elastic load balancer(ELB) and amazon certificate manager(ACM) of AWS.

The SSL certificate has issued and I applied to my load balancer, but HTTPS access always fail.

Do I have any additional steps for my HTTPS?

Comment: Please be more specific about *how* it "does not" work and "always fail."  What error messages do you see?

Comment: check the return HTTPS code

Comment: Sorry for late replying. All access with https returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Additionally, I'm using rails+Nginx+Passenger framework. When I open 443 port in my passenger, the error code is ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.